# How to add PPAs through a list?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I need to add PPAs on Ubuntu 14.04.3 from a file that contains a list of repositories, as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: $ (cat ppas.list) or sudo add-apt-repository $ (cat ppas.list) or yet cat ppas.list | xargs sudo add-apt-repository
```

But does not work and the following error appears: "Error: you need a single repository the argument" Can assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
for i in `cat ppas.list`; do sudo add-apt-repository $i; done
```